# error using the android youtube player

Tags: android, youtube

I'm trying to use the android youtube player in my application :
https://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/
but i got an erro while running on the phone :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity
```

here is what i wrote :

```
String urlStr= "http://www.youtube.com/user/armadamusic ";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlStr);
Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytpl://"+uri), this, OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
startActivity(lVideoIntent);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: So NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when JVM is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.

Comment: i know that but i don't know the cause of it, the lib is used & i did everything told on the website

Answer (score 0):

For OpenYouTubePlayerActivity, you need to add the Activity to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity" />
```